# remove all classes included in an array without loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
var fs = ['f1','f2','f3','f4','f5'];
$('button').on('click', function(){
  $('.title').removeClass('f1 f2 f3 f4 f5');
});
```

```css
.f1, .f2, .f3, .f4, .f5{
background:gold;
margin:2px 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='title f5'>lorem</div>
<div class='title f3'>lorem</div>
<div class='title f1'>lorem</div>
<div class='title f2'>lorem</div>
<button>CLICK</button>
```

This works, but I need to do this without writing all class names and without loop. Something like:

```
 $('.title').removeClass('all from fs');
```

Comment: You can use `.removeClass(fs)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you mean this?

```js
$('.title').removeClass(fs);
```

Also, what do you mean by *"without loop"*? Why can't you use a loop?

EDIT: Updated answer as per [jQuery's docs](https://api.jquery.com/removeclass/)

Comment: because of performances. The idea is to create string from array an use it inside removeClass